# Getting error - data.img failed to create in android x86

Tags: android-x86

Recently, I tried to install Android x86 (8.1) on my PC, When I gave the data.img size as default value i.e. 2048 MB it worked fine but when I gave it a larger size like 10240 MB (10 GB) it gives an error "data.img failed to create". What to do ? Even I have enough space on hard drive. I have created the partition with NTFS format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is the drive formatted? FAT32 has a 4GB limit...